# Линия от точки А до точки B

Tags: unity3d

Подскажите как примерно можно такое реализовать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно смотреть в сторону компонента под названием **[LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html)**

Comment: разве там можно задать текстуру для отображения?

Comment: там есть поле `Materials`. так что да. есть также просто поля для startColor и endColor

Comment: спасибо - но мне просто нужно отображать путь - где был замечен читер )

Comment: @Gapsy201 так, и?

Comment: @Я не как не пойму как сделать эту стрелку "Объемной" - чтобы на конце был такой конус

Comment: @Gapsy201 вопрос был про линию, а не про стрелку. и даже заголовок написан `Линия от точки А до точки B`